# Get email of user from Azure Ad login in Asp.Net Core application

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

We have an existing Asp.net Core application with username/password authentication (using SignInManager and UserManager and other classes from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity v2.2.0). I now added AzureAd sign-in by adding

```
services.AddSignIn(Configuration, "AzureAd");
```

and

```
.AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
```

and this config

```
"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
  "Domain": "[Enter the domain of your tenant, e.g. contoso.onmicrosoft.com]",
  "TenantId": "organizations",
  "ClientId": "xxx",
  "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
  "SignedOutCallbackPath ": "/signout-callback-oidc"
}
```

Now authentication in AzureAd seems to be working and it is POSTing back to /signin-oidc but that endpoint is unable to login the user.

How can I hook up my own custom code to the callback so I can get the e.g. the email address of the user that AzureAd has authenticated? Then if I trust the callback then I can login the user using the email.

As an additional question, can I trust that the all callbacks are actually from AzureAd?

Answer (score 0):

I found something within Microsoft Identity Web, for the custom code:

```
AddSignIn has another override, which takes delegates instead of a configuration section. The override with a configuration section actually calls the override with delegates.
```

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/web-apps#using-delegate-events

To be sure about proper callback request - based on acquired access token, you can execute MS Graph request to the '/me' endpoint, for fetching user data.

Here are Microsoft code samples for the ASP.net core, for many cases:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/